# k-means cluster heterogeneity in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

How to compute the cluster heterogeneity in sklearn during convergence?
Cluster heterogeneity is given by the total sum of the Euclidian distance of each sample point in respect to the assigned cluster. This presents a different value for each step.

Comment: Please indicate what you have already tried and why that didn't solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the cluster heterogeneity of the final k-means model you can do the following.

first create the model and fit it to some data (in my example I used the sklearn make blobs to create 3 blobs of datapoints).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances_argmin, euclidean_distances
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
np.random.seed(0)
batch_size = 45
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=3000, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.7)
k_means = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=3, n_init=10)
k_means.fit(X)
```

The model predicted these clusters. 
[image]

After the model has been fitted we need to have the centroids of all the clusters. For this you can use this.

```
k_means_cluster_centers = k_means.cluster_centers_
```

Then we need to know to what cluster all the datapoints in X belong to. For this you can use `pairwise_distances_argmin` this function returns the cluster any set of points have as their closest centroid.

```
k_means_labels = pairwise_distances_argmin(X, k_means_cluster_centers)
```

Then you need to compute the heterogeneity of all the clusters. To do this we need the following for loop and the `euclidean_distances` function. `euclidean_distances` calculates the euclidean distance between points.

```
for i,j in enumerate(set(k_means_labels)):
    positions=X[np.where(k_means_labels == i)]
    output=sum(euclidean_distances(positions,k_means_cluster_centers[j].reshape(1,-1)))
    print('cluster {} has a  heterogeneity of {}'.format(i,output))
```

In this loop we get all the values of X that belong to a cluster. Calculate the euclidean distance of all points to the centroid of that cluster. Take the sum and print the output.

For my example the output was this.

```
cluster 0 has a  heterogeneity of [ 754.20784445]
cluster 1 has a  heterogeneity of [ 852.41305495]
cluster 2 has a  heterogeneity of [ 843.7821897]
```

As far as I know you can only get the heterogeneity score after you have fitted the model and not during fitting the model with the sklearn implementation.

Comment: Finally I found that it is a limitation of sklearn. Graphlab is the only that I know that allows you to plot the heterogeneity during the computation.